# Is there any C API for releasing a job in slurm?

Tags: c, release, slurm, hpc

Is there any C API for "scontrol release <jobId>" in slurm? I'm trying to find a way to programmatically release a job (even trying to figure out how to hold job) using some APIs, but I can't find any such in slurm documentation or its source code.